# Python Dictionary sorting list into alphabetical order

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm, dictionary

I am trying to find the first unique character in a string. It is a LeetCode problem found here: https://leetcode.com/problems/first-unique-character-in-a-string/

Here is my code so far:

```
class Solution(object):
def firstUniqChar(self, s):
    """
    :type s: str
    :rtype: int
    """
    hashmap = {x: 0 for x in list(s)}
    
    for char in s:
        hashmap[char] += 1
    
    for k, v in hashmap.items():
        if v == 1:
            index = s.index(k)
            return index
```

The problem is when I split the string into the dictionary values the dictionary automatically places the characters in the string into alphabetical order.

Here is the output when I split the input string ---leetcode--- into a list:

[u'l', u'e', u'e', u't', u'c', u'o', u'd', u'e']

but when I print out the dictionary is shows this:

{u'c': 0, u'e': 0, u'd': 0, u'l': 0, u'o': 0, u't': 0}

notice how the duplicate characters are removed and it is sorted.

Now what is weird is that when running the same function in VScode the dictionary does not sort the list and my implementation works. Also it does not have the weird 'u' added.

Maybe its a LeetCode problem because I do not know why it adds the 'u' into the list and dictionary.

I need the dictionary to have the same order as the original string so I can find the FIRST non-repeating element in this case which is **l**
not **t** nor **c** nor **d** nor **o**.

Comment: You seem to be using different versions of python. One is v2.x (containing the "u" character) and the other one is v3.x (running in VSCode)

Comment: It looks like you have chosen python 2. At the drop-down list for languages, choose "Python3" instead of plain "Python".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since set() solution has been presented (which should be better in a *long long s*tring), here is alternative way to solve this one - just plain *str.index:*  (since is a given string, performance should not be real concern).

```py
 def firstUniqChar(self, s: str) -> int:
     letters = set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
     index = [s.index(c) for c in letters if s.count(c) == 1] # List Comp
     #print(index)
     return min(index) if len(index) > 0 else -1
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to keep track of the order of the characters in the input string.  You need to keep track of the index of the unique characters and return the smallest positive index.

```
class Solution:
    def firstUniqChar(self, s: str) -> int:
        seen = {}
        for i, c in enumerate(s):
            if seen.get(c) is not None:
                # This is not a unique character.
                seen[c] = -1
            else:
                seen[c] = i
        try:
            return min([rc for rc in seen.values() if rc >= 0])
        except:
            # If the list comp. above results in an empty list,
            # catch the exception and return -1.
            return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you see a "weird 'u'" added before each string tells you that the grading system uses Python 2, where Unicode strings have to be prefixed as such. Knowing this, you cannot rely on dicts retaining insertion order since this behavior was not officially supported until Python 3.7. Instead, use `collections.OrderedDict` in place of a dict in order to retain insertion order:

```
from collection import OrderedDict

...

hashmap = OrderedDict((x, 0) for x in s)
```

Comment: LeetCode already has Python 3.10, OP just needs to choose it.